ExceptionInInitializerError when using Hibernate OGM with MongoDB
I'm encountering an ExceptionInInitializerError while trying to run my Java application that uses Hibernate OGM to connect to a MongoDB database. Below are the relevant log messages and the stack trace that I'm seeing:
out. 20, 2024 2:30:39 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: ExemploJPA
    ...]
out. 20, 2024 2:30:39 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {[WORKING]}
out. 20, 2024 2:30:39 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.ogm.datastore.port=27017, hibernate.ogm.datastore.password=teste, hibernate.ogm.datastore.database=ebac, hibernate.ogm.datastore.username=teste, hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider=MONGODB, hibernate.ogm.mongodb.authentication_database=ebac, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.ogm.datastore.create_database=true, hibernate.ogm.datastore.host=127.0.0.1}
out. 20, 2024 2:30:40 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.3.Final}
out. 20, 2024 2:30:40 PM org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.impl.DatastoreProviderInitiator initiateService
INFO: OGM000016: NoSQL Datastore provider: org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider
out. 20, 2024 2:30:41 PM org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider createMongoClient
INFO: OGM001201: Connecting to MongoDB at 127.0.0.1:27017 with a timeout set at 10000 millisecond(s)
out. 20, 2024 2:30:41 PM com.mongodb.internal.diagnostics.logging.Loggers shouldUseSLF4J
WARNING: SLF4J not found on the classpath.  Logging is disabled for the 'org.mongodb.driver' component
out. 20, 2024 2:30:41 PM org.hibernate.ogm.cfg.impl.Version <clinit>
INFO: OGM000001: Hibernate OGM 5.4.2.Final
out. 20, 2024 2:30:41 PM org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider extractDatabase
INFO: OGM001207: Connecting to Mongo database named [ebac].

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/jdk.internal/misc/Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized0(Native Method)
    ...
    at br.com.deresende.mod34/br.com.deresende.dao.CursoDao.cadastrar(CursoDao.java:22)
    at br.com.deresende.mod34/br.com.deresende.CursoTest.cadastrar(CursoTest.java:23)
    ...

Context

I am using Hibernate OGM version 5.4.2 with Java 21.0.1.
My hibernate.properties file is configured to connect to a MongoDB instance running locally on 127.0.0.1:27017 with the database name ebac.
The error seems to be related to the initialization of a class in Hibernate OGM.
intellij community IDE
Windows 10
MongoDB Community

Steps I've Tried

Checked the hibernate.properties for any misconfiguration.
Ensured that MongoDB is running and accessible.
Verified that all necessary dependencies are included in my project.

Question
What could be causing this ExceptionInInitializerError, and how can I resolve it? Any guidance or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated!
github project
